# Creating bounding extent of existing polygon with same geometry using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, concave-hull

I have a number of polygons (in the hundreds) that have been taken from a cadastral layer and I am trying to create another polygon layer based on that group of polygons (from a field ID) without digitizing if possible?

I have looked at the convex hull tool in QGIS but it only creates the minimum boundary I am looking for an exact replica of the exisitng polygons - essentially removing all the parcels and being left with a singlepart polygon of the area.

I have access to ArcGIS as well if there are any tools suitable ?

[image: Selected Cadastre parcels]

and what I want to achieve is:

[image: Output of polygon]

Comment: Are you looking for just the tool in either QGIS or ArcMap?

Comment: Search old answers which contain "concave hull".

Comment: Im happy with arc or qgis as i have access to both.

Comment: I had a look through before  I posted but ill have  another in depth look

Comment: I recommend deciding whether you are trying to do this in one particular software within this question.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.  Otherwise, it is effectively two questions and violates the one question per question of the [Tour].

Comment: Ok thanks ill edit when i have something larger than a phone